# change the button each time a new tab is clicked in react from one child component to another child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm having difficulty passing state from child component `ConceptTabs.js` up to the parent, `App.js`, and then down to another child component `Audio.js`

I have a react app with a structure like this:

```
src/
  App.js
  components/
     header.js
     Audio2.js
     ConceptTabs.js
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./components/header";
import ConceptTabs from "./components/ConceptTabs";

function App() {

  let handleChange = (id) => {
    console.log("clicked", id);
    return id
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header currPage={handleChange} />
      <br />
        <ConceptTabs handleChangeProps={handleChange} />
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ConceptTabs.js

```
import React from "react";

function Tabs (props) {

  return (
    <>
     <button onClick={props.handleChangeProps(1)} > 
     ONE
    </button> 
    <br />
    <button onClick={props.handleChangeProps(1)} > 
     TWO
    </button> 
    <br />
    <button onClick={props.handleChangeProps(1)} > 
     THRE
    </button> 

    </>
  );
}

export default Tabs;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import Audio from "./Audio2"

function Header (props) {

  return (
     < Audio />
  );
}

export default Header;
```

and `Audio2.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Pause, Play } from "react-feather";
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";

function AudioPlayer(props) {

  // variable to play audio in loop
  const [isPlay, isPlaying] = useState(0);


  const [currPage, updatePageAudio] = useState({
    currPage: props.currPage,
  });

  const handlePlaying = () => {
    if (isPlay) {
      isPlaying(0);
    } else {
      isPlaying(1);
    }
  };

  console.log("Audio", currPage);

  return (
        <button
          onClick={handlePlaying}
        >
          <>{isPlay ? "Pause" : "Listen to this page"}</>
        </button>
  );
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

`App.js` renders `header.js` and `Concept.js`
When a user clicks a button on `Concept.js`
That should travel up to `App.js`
And then into `header.js` and then into `Audio2.js` where it will reset the button inside of `Audio2.js` to its original state.

I'm unsure of how to do this where I not only pass state up, but then pass it back down another branch into a child.

Here is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-states-ep03t?file=/src/components/Audio2.js:0-672

Currently, I've tried to add a function that is passed from `App.js` down to `ConceptTabs.js` to obtain info on what number is pushed, and then I've attempted to send this info back to `Audio2.js` But I'm not able to get this info to travel

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have your `handleChange` function in `App.js` set a state variable with the value passed up from `ConceptTabs.js`. Then pass that state variable (not `handleChange`) back down to `Audio.js`